# Firebase OnCall to Google Api Authentication

Tags: firebase, google-api, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to understand how to authenticate, as a user to the Google API (nodejs) in a Firebase Function, when I am calling the function via an onCall request

I am using Vue as my Front End, I have an authenticated user with the scopes I need.

The Firebase Function is getting called and `context.auth.token` is valid

```
const { google } = require('googleapis')
const webmasters = google.webmasters('v3')
const functions = require('firebase-functions')

async function runSample() {
    // Something here to set the auth on Google Options?
    // google.options({ auth })

    const res = await webmasters.searchanalytics.query({
        siteUrl: 'http://postmaker.io',

        requestBody: {
            startDate: '2018-01-01',
            endDate: '2018-04-01',
        },
    })
    console.log(res.data)
    return res.data
}

exports.myExample = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    return runSample()
})
```

I am thinking that possibly the token is valid for my app, but not against the Google Api.

The users are authenticating using the FirebaseUI and Firebase with their Google account.

Comment: Hi @Phil Duffy, what's your main objective on your question? Could you please check this [documentation](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client) and see if it helps.

Comment: I want to be able to call the GAPI as a user is the end goal